# Deleting features with identical table attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, delete, unique-value

How do I delete features with identical table attributes in QGIS? Otherwise, is there a tool like the 'Delete Identical Tool' in ArcGIS?

For example, if I had 4 rows, and 3 columns, where I wanted to delete identical features based on 2 columns:

| id | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | m |
| 2 | A | m |
| 3 | A | p |
| 4 | B | m |

I want it to be reduced to only 1 feature for each identical set of attributes:

| id | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | m |
| 3 | A | p |
| 4 | B | m |

In ArcGIS Desktop, this is a simple tool shown below called 'Delete Identical', where I can select one or more columns at the same time. I use this tool all the time, am switching to QGIS.

[image: arcgis]

Comment: I posted this elsewhere in Stackoverflow, and it got downvoted -1 with no explanation. If you downvote, can you please tell me why??

Comment: Always some lamers downvoting there. Maybe because you havent attempted anything on your own

Comment: @BERA, you are so right!

Answer (score 11):

For future reference: the next version of QGIS (3.6) includes a built-in ['Delete duplicates by attribute'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicates-by-attribute) tool which does exactly this.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, but it should delete the feature with a minimal value of an attribute. For example, I have two lines with same name, I would like it to delete one with the shortest length. Is this possible?

Comment: @ar-siddiqui, please ask it as [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3, you could use ['Add autoincremental field'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) tool to distinguish the identical set of attribute fields.

If your `ABC` field holds `A`, `B`, ... and `mnp` field holds `m`, `p`, ... like below image;

[image]

Select these `ABC`, `mnp` fields in the *Group values by* option, and keep other options at the default setting.

[image]

This tool will return a new `Incremental` layer. You will see `AUTO` field with `0` and `1`. (You may have `2` or bigger numbers if you have many duplicated records).

[image]

Select and highlight `AUTO`= 0 and go to **Save As**, using `only selected features` option.

Comment: How does your answer solve the problem that was to remove the duplicates?

Comment: @user30184 I think it is the last part (saving only the record with `0`), which creates  new data without duplicates.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Comment: @Kazuhito

Great, I'll check it out. Unfortunately, generating the original table is now not working for me - I've identified duplicate geometry in the past with ArcGIS using the "find identical" tool, choosing "shape", but it's not working. I'm trying to do it with QGIS as well. I don't want to delete features with identical geometry, I just want to add a common id for duplicates. Any idea on how to do that?

I've posted this question here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302215/identify-identical-geometry-in-column-with-common-number-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility of using a ['Virtual Layer'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is a point layer `'testpoints'` with identical table attributes, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to *delete features with identical table attributes*.

```sql
SELECT "id", "value1", "value2", geometry
FROM "testpoints"
GROUP BY "value1", "value2"
```

The output layer with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]

*P.S.* Mind that this solution does make sense if features possess the same geometry

---

**References:**

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)