# Identify identical geometry in column with common number in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to identify identical (or duplicate) geometry in QGIS by adding a common number for each identical set. For example, if there are 4 features, and 2 are identical:

1| Identical with 2

2| Identical with 1

3|

4|

I want the following:

1|1

2|1

3|2

4|3

With ArcGIS, there is a tool called "Find Identical" that creates a table for geometry duplicates - you choose a shapefile and choose "Shape" under the list to identify within, and it produces a table of identicals, as above. Here is a screenshot of the tool:

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between this question the question you have before? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302118/how-do-i-delete-features-with-identical-table-attributes-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

There is **Add unique value index field** tool in QGIS 3.

(1) Preparation: create a WKT attribute field by `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` using the Field Calculator.

[image]

(2) Start **Add unique value index field** tool (in `Processing Toolbox | Vector table`) and assign your WKT field to `Class field`.

[image]

Output field (e.g. `NUM_FIELD`) has index number starting from 0. Probably you need to add 1 to obtain what you want (`1, 2, 3...`).

[image]